# TypeORM one to one relation using primary key as foreign key

Tags: typeorm

I am having troubles setting an one to one relation in TypeORM using primary key as foreign key.

Entities:

```js
import { BaseEntity, Entity, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    user: string;

}
```

```js
import { BaseEntity, Entity, JoinColumn, OneToOne, PrimaryColumn } from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./User";

@Entity()
export class Profile extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryColumn()
    @JoinColumn({ name: "user" })
    @OneToOne(() => User, entity => entity.user)
    user: User;

}
```

Code:

```js
const userEntity = User.create({
    user: "my-user-id",
});

await userEntity.save();

const profileEntity = Profile.create({
    user: userEntity,
});

await profileEntity.save();
```

Produces error:

```
TypeError: Cannot create property 'user' on string 'my-user-id'
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/lucian-tanase/typeorm-one-to-one/main

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.